# Technical terms linking vertical lists to Instructions

Tags: usability, gui-design, lists, instructions

I once read a study where it described that displaying information vertically hints/implies to the user that it is instructions. I tried searching for proof of this concept again and couldn't find it this time.

Does anyone know any key terms/concepts relating to information being displayed vertically rather than horizontally means its implying that the information is instructions/guidelines to follow.

Heres an example of what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I once read a study where it described that displaying information
>   vertically hints/implies to the user that it is instructions.

This is an interesting idea. Was it referring to printed or online content? If online, was it some time ago?

In a work full of apps (and sites) where people spend a lot of time scrolling through posts, images, and videos, I wouldn't have thought it is still relevant.

I would still be interested in reading the article if you find it.

Comment: I can't remember too much about it, someone briefly showed me it quickly and it wasn't directly applicable to what I was working on at the time but they mentioned it relating to online content. If I find anything about it I'll post it on this question